# How to pin script frame to actions panel in Flash CC 2014 like it was in Flash CS6

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cc

In Flash Pro CS6 there was a very useful "Pin Current Script" button on action panel. I used it in all my projects.

In Flash CC 2014 it is not there any more and every time I select an object, the script window shows the script on symbol or frame I have selected. I need my main script and other frames to be pinned like in Flash CS6.

Is there any way to pin script frames to scripts panel in CC 2014?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have noticed, pinning scripts has been deprecated in CC: https://forums.adobe.com/message/6137313

Instead, you'll have to use the Framescript Navigator to click between frame scripts:
[image: Framescript Navigator]

Comment: This is rather unfortunate though as this feature was pretty helpful.

Comment: I would like to suggest that anyone using the Flash IDE to write ActionScript should look at FlashDevelop. It's free, open-source, and has countless features that Flash does not have.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that it is only available for the windows platform though.  I had looked into it in the past, and although I run Windows using Parallels and VirtualBox on my Apple computer, I forgo using Flash Develop because they don't offer a version for OS X.

Comment: I switched to FlashDevelop some period ago and this is really much more comfortable than coding in Flash IDE. Thanks!